# how can I find peaks of a audio for each second?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I need to find the peaks in a audio for each second. so if audio is 300 second long, I need to find 300 peaks for that audio. So one peak per second. is it possible to do that with ffprobe? how can I do that?

Comment: Of what possible benefit could that be? Some kind of compressor, auto-levelling? I'm not sure dividing it up into equal seconds is really how to approach that task.

Comment: Can you explain the context? Also, your question is ambiguous: do you need 300 peaks, or do you need one peak for each slice of 1 s length?

Comment: @slhck I need to find one peak per second. so that means 300 peaks for 300 second audio.

Comment: Still not clear. Do you have to find one peak for each 1 second slice, or could there be two (or more) peaks within a one second slice of audio? (In other words, can the file be split into chunks before, or do you just have to find the 300 “highest” peaks?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344888/getting-max-amplitude-for-an-audio-file-per-second